# hit back in the browser

Tags: asp.net

When i hit back in the browser the user is still logged in. can someone help please?

Comment: What is your problem with this? You want user to be logged off when he clicks back?

Comment: yes, I want the user to be logged off

Comment: Alina - please revisit your previous questions and tick the answer that best answers your questions. Many people will not answer your questions now because they feel, based on your previous activity, that they will not get credit for their effort.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming mean:

"After the user logs out, if they then press back in the browser the page says they are still logged in. How do I stop this?"

If so, what the user is seeing is the browsers *cached* version of the page - they are not actually still logged in, and if they were to browse elsewhere, then they would see that they are now logged out.

I often get around this by having the [LoginStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginstatus.aspx) control have a [LogoutAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginstatus.logoutaction.aspx) of `Redirect`, and the [LogoutPageUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginstatus.logoutpageurl.aspx) set to something like the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

That is the correct behaviour for most web applications. Being logged in is a question of state, and does not rely on the page you are viewing.

If you want the back button to log the user out, then it would seem that it is a case of whichever page the previous one was, is where you want logged in users to be automatically logged out. It might be the case that the previous page (accessed through the back option) is the login page, where you would want logged in users to automatically be logged out.

To get a more accurate and more helpful answer, you should specify what behaviour you are expecting, and include details about the authentication system you are using (for example ASP.NET membership).